# K&R Exercise 6-2 - Self referencing Structures

Tags: c, struct, tree, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am trying to do Exercise 6-2 of K&R, the text  of the exercise is:

> Exercise 6-2. Write a program that reads a C program and prints in alphabetical order each group of variable names that are identical in the first 6 characters, but different somewhere thereafter . Don’t count words within strings and comments. Make 6 a parameter that can be set from the command line.

The way I tried to resolve this is by having two structures, a structure `group` which will contain groups of words with identical 6 first characters:

```
struct group {
  struct group *left;
  struct group *right;
  struct word *word;
};
```

`left` and `right` point to the groups immediately preceding and immediately following the current one alphabetically, the structure `word`:

```
struct word{
  char *value;
  struct word *left;
  struct word *right;
};
```

will contain the string for a word read on the input in `value`, `left` and `right` point to the words immediately preceding and immediately following the current one alphabetically.

I use the functions `addgroup`and `addword` to allocate memory for new `groups`/`words` :

```
struct word *addword(struct word *w, char *s)
{
  printf("[START]: addword(%s, %s)\n", (w == NULL ? "(null)": w->value), s);
  if(w == NULL){
    struct word *new_word = (struct word *) malloc(sizeof(struct word));
    if(new_word) {
      printf("[START]: Creating new word %s \n", s);
      new_word->left = NULL;
      new_word->right = NULL;
      new_word->value = strdup(s);
      printf("[END]: Created new word %s \n", new_word->value);
      return new_word;
      }
      else{
    printf("ERROR: Couldn't allocate memory for %s\n", s);
    return NULL;
      }
    }
    else if(strcmp(s, w->value) < 0){
      printf("[START]: Adding %s to left of %s\n", s, w->value);
      w->left = addword(w->left, s);
      printf("[END]: Added %s to left of %s\n", s, w->value);
    }
    else if(strcmp(s, w->value) > 0){
      printf("[START]: Adding %s to right of %s\n", s, w->value);
      w->right = addword(w->right, s);
      printf("[END]: Added %s to right of %s\n", s, w->value);
    }
    return w;
}

struct group *galloc()
{
  return (struct group *) malloc(sizeof(struct group));
}



struct group *addgroup(struct group *g, char *s)
{
  char *temp;
  if(g == NULL)
    {
      temp = strndup(s, 6);
      printf("[START]: creating new group %s\n", temp);
      struct group *new_group = galloc();
      if(new_group) {
    new_group->left = NULL;
    new_group->right = NULL;
    new_group->word = addword(NULL, s);
    printf("[END]: created new group %s\n", temp);
    return new_group;
      }
      else{
    printf("[ERROR]: Could not allocate space to new group\n");
    return NULL;
      }
    }
  else if(strncmp(s, (g->word)->value, 6) < 0) {
    printf("[START]: Adding word %s to left of group %s \n", s, strncpy(temp, (g->word)->value, 6));
    g->left = addgroup(g->left, s);
    printf("[END]: Added word %s to left of group %s \n", s, strncpy(temp, (g->word)->value, 6));
  }
  else if(strncmp(s, (g->word)->value, 6) > 0) {
    printf("[START]: Adding word %s to right of group %s \n", s, strncpy(temp, (g->word)->value, 6));
    g->right = addgroup(g->right, s);
    printf("[END]: Added word %s to right of group %s \n", s, strncpy(temp, (g->word)->value, 6));
      }
  else {
    printf("[START]: Adding word %s to group %s \n", s, strncpy(temp, (g->word)->value, 6));
    g->word = addword(g->word, s);
    printf("[END]: Added word %s to group %s \n", s, strncpy(temp, (g->word)->value, 6));
  }
  return g;
}
```

My problem: The code works for the first 3 words and then crashes with a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error, here's an example of output (in my main function I print the whole tree of groups after each new word):

```
> Falsefiable
[START]: creating new group Falsef
[START]: addword((null), Falsefiable)
[START]: Creating new word Falsefiable 
[END]: Created new word Falsefiable 
[END]: created new group Falsef
Falsefiable

...After adding words Falsefact, Falsefiable, and Printingpress, all without a problem...

Falsefact
Falsefiable
Printingpress

> Printing
[START]: Adding word Printing to right of group Falsef 
[START]: Adding word Printing to group Printi 
[START]: addword(Printingpress, Printing)
[START]: Adding Printing to left of Printingpress
[START]: addword((null), Printing)
[START]: Creating new word Printing 
[END]: Created new word Printing 
[END]: Added Printing to left of Printingpress
[END]: Added word Printing to group Printi 
[END]: Added word Printing to right of group Falsef 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Using `valgrind` all I could learn was that the problem is caused by `Access not within mapped region at address`

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

EDIT 1: my `main` function

```
#define MAXWORD 100

int main(int agrc, char *argv[])
{
  char word[MAXWORD];
  struct group *root = NULL;
  while( getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF)
    if(isalpha(word[0])){
      root = addgroup(root, word);
       printgroup(root);
    }     
  return 0;
}
```

functions `getword`:

```
char getword(char *word, int l)
{
  int c, i;
  while(isspace(c = getch()))
    ;

  i = 0;
  word[i++] = c;

  if(!isalpha(c)){
    word[i] = '\0';
    return c;
  }

  while(isalnum(c = getch()) && i < l-1)
    word[i++] = c;
  word[i] = '\0';

  ungetch(c);
  return word[0];
}
```

and `getch/ungetch`:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 100

int buffer[BUFFSIZE];
int buffp = 0;

int getch(void)
{
  if(buffp > 0)
    return buffer[--buffp];
  else
    return getchar();
}
void ungetch(int c)
{
  if(buffp <  BUFFSIZE - 1)
    buffer[buffp++] = c;
  else
    printf("ERROR: Not enough space in buffer\n");

}
```

EDIT 2: cleaning question and adding `valgrind`output

This is what `valgrind`'s output right after the last line of the program's output when crash happens :

```
[END]: Added word Printing to right of group Falsef 
==13993== Invalid write of size 8
==13993==    at 0x1090CB: main (in /home/me/The C Programming Language/Chapter 6/6-2/main)
==13993==  Address 0x69746e6971d8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13993==
==13993==
==13993== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==13993==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x69746E6971D8
==13993==    at 0x1090CB: main (in /home/me/The C Programming Language/Chapter 6/6-2/main)
==13993==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==13993==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==13993==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==13993==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==13993==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8720384.
==13993==
==13993== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13993==     in use at exit: 203 bytes in 12 blocks
==13993==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 2 frees, 2,251 bytes allocated
==13993==
==13993== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13993==    definitely lost: 14 bytes in 2 blocks
==13993==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13993==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13993==    still reachable: 189 bytes in 10 blocks
==13993==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13993== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13993==
==13993== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13993== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==13993== ERROR SUMMARY: 315 errors from 67 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Where is the `main` function? The problem may be _there_.

Comment: I had omitted it along with functions `getword` and `getch`/`ungetch`  that I use to get input because I thought my question was already too long.
I just edited my question and added them

Comment: That is too long, at it is stll not a [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene, I realize that, problem is I don't know where the problem comes from...what do you recommend removing?

Comment: First off, what does your debugger tell you? Which line crashes and what are the values of variables at that point? What's the complete valgrind output?

Comment: just edited my question and added that

Comment: Compile your program with `-g` and run valgrind again. Do you get more information?

Comment: What is `getword`? What is `MAXWORD`? What is `printgroup`.

Comment: sadly no, and options `--track-origins=yes` and `--leak-check=full` to `valgrind` didn't help

Comment: @MichaelWalz sorry removed them because my question was already too long, I added them back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one problem here:

```
struct group *addgroup(struct group *g, char *s)
{
  char *temp;
  if (g == NULL)
  {
    temp = strndup(s, 6);
    ...
  }
  else if (strncmp(s, (g->word)->value, 6) < 0) {
    printf("[START]: Adding word %s to left of group %s \n", s, strncpy(temp, (g->word)->value, 6));
    ...                                                                  ^
                                                                         |
                                          temp may be uninitialized here |
```

If `g` is not `NULL`, then `temp` is not initialized and dereferencing an uninitialized pointer will result in all sorts of nasty things AKA *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: WOW, I was not looking there, thank you so much, that was it!

Comment: Your debugger would have told you where it crashed and from there you would have found out yourself.

Comment: I only use valgrind, and looking at its output didn't help me much, are you referring to something else I can use to debug my programs?

Comment: @Ryuuzaki_kun what is your platform, compiler, IDE etc. ?

Comment: I run Linux, write in Emacs, and compile using gcc

Comment: @Ryuuzaki_kun then you need to compile with `gcc -g` and use the `gdb` debugger. There are plenty of tutorials and docs on the net.